# Simplest way to create multiple-language one-page website

Tags: html, web, localization, multilingual

There are plenty of questions likes this, but I've read many of them and what I saw appears to be too complex for my very simplistic case.

I have a super simple one-page website ([picstalk.app](https://picstalk.app) in case you care). It is nothing more than a few divs with text. I'm looking for the simplest way possible to have that in multiple languages, so that the text with the browser's default language is shown automatically and of course there is a way to switch languages manually.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is efficient but since you have very little text, This will work.

```js
// Maintain a supported Language List
var langList = ['en', 'zh'];
// Get browser Language
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
// extract Language (en-US => en)
userLang = userLang.substring(0, 2);
// Call the function to set language
changeLang(userLang);

// function to change language
function changeLang(lang) {
  langList.forEach((langEle) => {
    // if language matches, display
    if (langEle == lang) {
      var langElems = document.querySelectorAll('.' + langEle)
      langElems.forEach((elem) => {
        elem.style.display = "block"
      })
    }
    // hide the language text
    else {
      hideLang(langEle)
    }
  })
}

// function to hide language
function hideLang(lang) {
  var langElems = document.querySelectorAll('.' + lang)
  langElems.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.style.display = "none"
  })
}
```

```html
<h1><span lang="en" class="en">Hello</span> <span lang="zh" class="zh">你好</span></h1>
<button onclick="changeLang('en')">English</button><button onclick="changeLang('zh')">Chinese</button>
```

Comment: *Accept* and *Upvote* if helped.

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising, but doesn't actually work for me. I read somewhere that you cannot override style.display from JS if it was defined in CSS...

Comment: Weird...querySelectorAll returns an empty list...

Comment: It works! the problem was tests I put that <script> in <head> instead of <body>. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Javascript** to do it. At first, you have to create `web pages` for different `languages` and have a `default language` on the `landing page`. And then you have to `add` a `switching button` for `users` who want to use your website in their language.